# Edit a collection of Models with one controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a template that allows me to edit settings of a user. Within the usersettings my model is the actual user. And I have a 1-N Relationship between User-Settings:

```
{{#if isEditing}}
    <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
{{else}}
    <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
{{/if}}
<h1>Settings</h1>
  {{#each this.setting}}
      {{#if isEditing}}
          {{name}}: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='value'}}
      {{else}}
          {{name}}: {{value}}
      {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

The problem is that if I click the Edit button, the "Edit" status is only coming to main controllere here. So my Buttons change, but within the loop, the Textfield is not appearing.

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        edit: function(){
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        doneEditing: function(){
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        },
    }
});
```

(I don't have a specific controller for the SettingItems in my Loop)

How do I handle such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you definitely can do it.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uwENUbeh/3/edit